# Apache Web Server is accessed from LAN but website (virtual host) not accessible from LAN

Tags: apache

When I try to Apache web address (192.168.0.21) from LAN computers, it is accessed successfully.

I have created one website 10000MT in Apache web server and written below code in etc/apache2/sites-avaiable/10000MT.conf file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "var/www/10000MT"
    ServerName 10000MT
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I try to access this website using 192.168.0.21/10000MT, it is giving below error message.

```
Not Found

The requested URL /10000MT was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.0.21 Port 80
```

Please let me know what changes I need to do to access this website from LAN computers. But I can access site without any issue from linux pc but not from other pcs from LAN.

Comment: Not 100℅ sure, but i think apache virtual hosts are resolved by domain name, so you can't access them with an    IP.

Comment: so what should I do? and how? Please let me know

Comment: Check http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/ip-based.html

Comment: @xvan, I did what is mentioned in above referred link but still no luck... please let me know what further I can do...ty